# Why won't my UISearchBar obey constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, uisearchbar

In my iOS app I have a navigation bar composed of a `UISearchBar` and a `UIButton` in a `UIStackView`. Since I can't storyboard a `UISearchController` I have a blank `UIView` in the stack view and I'm adding the `UISearchBar` as a subview. Here's what my storyboard looks like:[image]

Here's my code to add the search bar

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureSearchController()
    print(wrapperView.bounds)
    print(searchController.searchBar.bounds)
}

func configureSearchController() {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.searchBar.isTranslucent = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = addButton.backgroundColor
    wrapperView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    let color = addButton.backgroundColor
    searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
    searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = color?.cgColor
    searchController.searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addButton.leadingAnchor)
}
```

But the search bar goes past the `UIButton`, as shown here:
[image]
How can I get the `UISearchBar` to end at the `UIButton` like this?
[image]

Comment: Try to move the button above the wrapper view in the uiobject list

Comment: @SaintThread That puts the `UIButton` in front of the search bar.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question, can you show use the constraints of wrapper view? Maybe you have the trailing to parentview and not to button

Comment: Here's the weird thing: if I click on the search bar and bring up the keyboard all is well. I'm assuming that's because it's updating the view. Is there a way to force the view to update? That might fix my problem

Comment: @SaintThread I don't have constraints on the wrapper view because it's in a stack view. You don't need constraints in a stack view

Comment: Try calling setNeedsUpdateConstraints or layoutIfNeeded at the end of configureSearchController

Comment: @SaintThread Neither worked for me

Comment: I made it print out the bounds of the search bar and wrapperView in viewDidLoad and I got (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 44.0) and (0.0, 0.0, 1000.0, 1000.0), respectively. Why is the width and height of wrapperView 1000?

Comment: I answered with a proposal, before downvoting tell me in the comments if you have problems

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
searchController.searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addButton.leadingAnchor)
```

with:

```
searchController.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
wrapperView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[subview]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["subview": searchController]))
wrapperView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[subview]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["subview": searchController]))
```

**EDIT:**
Otherwise try with a UISearchController:

```
searchController.searchBar.setImage(<image_name>, forSearchBarIcon: .Bookmark, state: .Normal)
```

this will allow you to add a custom button near the search bar.

Comment: Swift 3 won't let me pass nil in for options

Comment: try an empty array: `[]`

Comment: It took the empty array but now the app crashes

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISearchController nsli_superitem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8050e071c0'

Comment: This is where I wish Apple just let us storyboard `UISearchController`. This will be the third straight Xcode with no storyboard support for `UISearchController`

Comment: "This is where I wish Apple just let us storyboard UISearchController" It's neither a view controller nor a view, so how exactly would that even work?

Comment: Add the Bookmark image to your searchController.searchBar and remove your external button.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, follow this guide: https://www.appcoda.com/custom-search-bar-tutorial/ from the section `The Custom Search Controller`

Comment: Won't using a bookmark image put the image inside the searchBar? I want the button outside the search bar like in a navigation bar

Comment: I just don't understand why my constraints aren't being applied. No matter what constraint I put on wrapperView it still has bounds of (0, 0, 1000, 1000)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, and I was able to fix it by calling `searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()` after adding it to my view (right after the `addSubview()` line). You might have to run `wrapperView.layoutIfNeeded()` before, so something like this:

```
wrapperView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
wrapperView.layoutIfNeeded()
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
```

Hope it helps!